# Data binding broken in Vue 3 component

Tags: vuejs3

The following (abbreviated) code takes input values from a form, calculates a new value from those data and - is supposed to - returns the result (myanswer) to the user.

```
<template>
  <va-form ref="formRef" class="flex flex-col gap-2 mb-2">
    <div class="calcset">
      <div class='calleft'><span class="va-title">Required concentration</span></div>
      <div class='calright'>
        <va-input
          v-model="form.ppmreqd"      
          preset="solid"
          mask="numeral"            
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="calcset">
      <div class='calleft'><span class="va-title">Required volume</span></div>
      <div class='calright'>
        <va-input
          v-model="form.howmuch"      
          preset="solid"
          mask="numeral"            
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
    <p v-if="myanswer !== null">Calculated value: {{ myanswer }}</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <va-button :disabled="!isValid" @click="validate() && submit()"
      class="mt-3"
      color="#873a48"
    >
      Calculate
    </va-button></div>
  </va-form>
 </template>

 <script setup>
  import { ref,reactive, } from 'vue'
  import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
  import { useForm } from 'vuestic-ui'
  const { isValid, validate } = useForm('formRef')
  const route = useRoute(); 
  const form = reactive({
    ppmreqd: '',
    howmuch: '',
  })
  let myanswer = null;
  const submit = () => {
    const calcID = route.params.id;
    const ppmreqd = parseFloat(form.ppmreqd);
    const howmuch = parseFloat(form.howmuch);

   if (!isNaN(ppmreqd) && !isNaN(howmuch)) {
     myanswer = ppmreqd * howmuch;
   } else {
     myanswer = null; 
   }
   //console.log(myanswer)
  }
  </script>
```

Despite a valid value being calculated (myanswer), it is not appearing in its designated position in the template.

What have I done wrong here?

Thanks, Tom

Comment: `myanswer` is not reactive. Turn it into a ref, i.e. `const myanswer = ref(null)`

Comment: Assume you meant let myanswer = ref(null) (let, because myanswer's value is/maybe going to be reassigned.  Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: No, I did mean const. You don't override refs, but rather set their value. You should [read up](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html) on them, they are quite fundamental.

Comment: `myanswer` should be a ref as already stated, but also when you update a ref you need to assign the inner value, which means updating the lines that say `myanswer = ` to `myanswer.value = `.  There are two lines that need to be updated, then it should work.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you both for your patience and input. Happily onwards.